# Need to do performance test for a client server application using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, blazemeter

I need to install a desktop app into 1000 users machine and after installation each request to be hit to server at regular time intervals. For all the requests the user should be different and once install service is called I don't want to call it again in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on protocol your application is using:

1. If it is [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) - you can even record it using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and replay with [increased number of threads](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_users) (virtual users). You will need to configure your application to use JMeter as a proxy, check out [How to Run Performance Tests of Desktop Applications Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter) for more details.
2. If it is one of the protocols supported by other JMeter [Samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) or [Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Samplers) you need to figure out what is happening under the hood and configure JMeter accordingly.
3. Finally you can just record the traffic between your application and backend using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org/) and replay it using JMeter's [TCP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler) but in this case it will be tricky to parameterise the requests, extract values from response, making assertions, etc.

No matter which option you choose in order to fire request at regular time intervals don't forget to add [Constant Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) to introduce delays as by default JMeter will execute one request after another.